# How to add callback to MKAnnotationView?

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I need to add click listener to all annotationView. This listener opens another view controller. 
I wrote this code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let selected = (view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation) {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.selectedAnnotation = selected
    }
}
@objc func tapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    if let controller = DetailsController.storyboardInstance(){
        if let selectedAnnotation = selectedAnnotation{
            controller.selectedAnnotation = selectedAnnotation
            mapView.deselectAnnotation(selectedAnnotation, animated: false)
        }
        self.present(controller, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

`tapped` listener opens another view controller. But when I dismiss this view controller MkAnnotationView is still selected. How to close it? Is there any other way to add callback to all MkAnnotationView?

Comment: mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)

Comment: the problem is mkannotationview doesn't appear the second time I click it. It opens controller instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `MKAnnotationView.setSelected(_:animated:)`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    ...
    view.setSelected(false, animated: false)
}
```

Or `MKMapView.deselectAnnotation(_:animated:)`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let selected = view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation {
        ...
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(selected, animated: false)
    }
}
```

**Update-1**

```
if let annotationView = mapView.view(for: selected) {
    annotationView.setSelected(false, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: mkannotationview doesn't open, when I wrote mapView.deselectAnnotation(selected, animated: false)

Comment: I add this code to method, which opens another view controller. It helps me, but when I click on this annotation again, annotation view doesn't appear, but appears only another view controller. I updated code.

Comment: the problem is mkannotationview doesn't appear the second time I click it. It opens controller instead

Comment: When you tap empty map area and again tap the annotation, then the annotation view appears? is it the case? try the update, `annotationView.setSelected(false, animated)`

Comment: First I click on annotation, then annotation view appears, then I click on annotation view and 2nd view controller shows up. It's right. Then I close 2nd view controller, annotation view closes too, it's ok. But when I click on the same annotation on the map, annotation view doesn't appear, instead 2nd view controller opens immediately. That not the behaviour I want. I want to click on annotation, after that click on annotation view, and only then open 2nd view controller

Answer (score 0):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    if view.annotation is MKClusterAnnotation
    {
      view.setSelected(false, animated: false)
      return
    }

 customview = UINib(nibName: "CustomViewForAnnotation", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CustomViewForAnnotation
 customview.initialize(textForCell: "Spacious #3BHK #Flat sale in ABA Cleo County #Sector121 #Noida 201307 #Apartment #ForSale #Residential #Property", placeName: "fgfvf", cellCount: 2)

    customview.loadCell(customview)

    view.addSubview(customview)

    }



   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    customview.removeFromSuperview()
   }
```